# SSRS - Obtaining the physical report files

Tags: reporting-services

Basically I have a reports server which contains loads of "My Reports" reports which I need to migrate to a new SSRS server.

**Question:**

Is their an easy way to obtain all the physical.RDL files without having to export the files one-by-one from the old server interface and then upload using the new servers interface?

Looking forward to your reply

Steven

Answer (score 1):

You could write a small .NET app to retrieve them all, using the SSRS Web Service API. The [article on the GetItemDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.getitemdefinition.aspx) method has sample code to get a single file, here's a relevant snippet (copy/paste alert!):

```cs
ReportingService2010 rs = new ReportingService2010();
rs.Url = "http://<Server Name>/_vti_bin/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx";
rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

string reportName = "http://<Server Name>/Docs/Documents" 
                    + "/AdventureWorks Sample Reports/Sales Order Detail.rdl";
byte[] reportDefinition = null;
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

try
{
    reportDefinition = rs.GetItemDefinition(reportName);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(reportDefinition);

    string myDocumentsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

    doc.Load(stream);
    doc.Save(Path.Combine(myDocumentsFolder, "Sales Order Detail.rdl"));
}
```

If you write a little loop around (part of) this code you may be able to quickly grab all the files.